# Can't use nested form on belongs_to Model - how should I handle this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got two models: `Clients` and `Projects`.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

and

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

I have three requirements for my app:

- I want to be able to go to a Client page that lists all projects that belong to that client
- I want Projects to be created from `/projects/new/`, with a dropdown box on the form that lists all Clients to select the assocation
- I want a user to be able to add a new Client from that same form (last item on the dropdown from item #1 is "add new") so they can create a Project and a Client at the same time if needed

What's throwing me off is item #3. I assumed to be able to add a new Client from the Project form, I'd have to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on `Project`, but I can't do that on a `belongs_to` model.

Am I architecting this wrong? How should I handle this? I haven't been able to find a sufficient answer, but this seems trivial to handle.

Thanks!

Comment: From your server log, is the child params being sent? Since you're on Rails 4, the problem is most likely be that you're not "permiting" the params of the child project from the Client controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This railscast will explain it far better than I can in a few words here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

In essence though, you need to change the way you're thinking about the relations. It should be that the Client accepts_nested_attributes_for its Projects. So whilst you may do this through your projects controller, you'll actually be creating a `form_for @client` ...

Comment: I think that makes sense. In terms of code organization, would I put my Project form in `app/views/projects/` or `app/views/clients`?

Comment: You could use the nested form `app/views/clients/projects` if you set up your nested resources correctly. Also, don't think of the controller as a form. They're quite different things.